# operand broadcast for numpy subtraction

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, statistics

I have been working with getting the Q-residual and Hotelling's T statistics for PCA models and currently I am trying the equation from PCA to be used with LDA model. Equations can be found using the following links: ([T-Squared & Q_residuals with their Contributions](http://wiki.eigenvector.com/index.php?title=T-Squared_Q_residuals_and_Contributions)) and ([Outliers detection pls-regression NIR spectroscopy python](https://nirpyresearch.com/outliers-detection-pls-regression-nir-spectroscopy-python/)). However, while following the same steps in the link, I keep on getting stuck at the matrix subtraction part. Here is the following function for Q-Residual calculation,

Code:

```
def Q_Residual_index_LDA(input_features, LDA_scores, LDA_loading, eigenvalues):
    input_len = np.array(input_features).shape
    LDA_scores = LDA_scores
    LDA_loading = LDA_loading
    eigenvalues = eigenvalues

    Q_eq_1 = np.dot(LDA_scores, np.array(LDA_loading).reshape(2,50))
    Q_err = np.mat(input_features) - np.mat(Q_eq_1)
    # Q_err = np.subtract(np.array(input_features), np.array(Q_eq_1).reshape(50,50))
    Q_res = np.sum(Q_err**2, axis=1)
    
    # Q_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([np.array(LDA_loading).reshape(50,2), np.array(LDA_loading).reshape(2,50)])
    # # print(np.shape(Q_eq_1))
    # Q_eq_2 = np.identity(input_len[1]) - Q_eq_1
    # Q_res = np.linalg.multi_dot([input_features, Q_eq_2, input_features.T])
    
    # Contribution:
    #### CDC:
    # Q_res_CDC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot(LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T)
    Q_res_CDC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T])
    eye_M = np.identity(input_len[1])
    Q_res_CDC = np.array(np.diag(np.linalg.multi_dot([input_features, (Q_res_CDC_eq_1 ** 0.5), eye_M.T, eye_M, (Q_res_CDC_eq_1 ** 0.5), input_features.T])))
    Q_res_CDC = np.where(np.isnan(Q_res_CDC), 0, Q_res_CDC)
    
    #### PDC:
    # Q_res_PDC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot(LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T)
    Q_res_PDC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T])
    eye_M = np.identity(input_len[1])
    Q_res_PDC = np.array(np.diag(np.linalg.multi_dot([input_features, Q_res_PDC_eq_1, eye_M.T, eye_M, input_features.T])))
    Q_res_PDC = np.where(np.isnan(Q_res_PDC), 0, Q_res_PDC)
    
    #### DC:
    # Q_res_DC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot(LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T)
    Q_res_DC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T])
    eye_M = np.identity(input_len[1])
    Q_res_DC = np.array(np.diag(np.linalg.multi_dot([input_features, eye_M.T, eye_M, Q_res_DC_eq_1, eye_M.T, eye_M, input_features.T])))
    Q_res_DC = np.where(np.isnan(Q_res_DC), 0, Q_res_DC)
    
    #### RBC:
    # Q_res_RBC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot(LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T)
    Q_res_RBC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T])
    eye_M = np.identity(input_len[1])
    Q_res_RBC_eq_2 = np.linalg.multi_dot([eye_M, Q_res_RBC_eq_1, eye_M.T])
    Q_res_RBC = np.array(np.diag(np.linalg.multi_dot([input_features, Q_res_RBC_eq_1, eye_M.T, np.linalg.pinv(Q_res_RBC_eq_2), eye_M, Q_res_RBC_eq_1, input_features.T])))
    Q_res_RBC = np.where(np.isnan(Q_res_RBC), 0, Q_res_RBC)
    
    # #### ABC (1):
    # # # Q_res_ABC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot(LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T)
    # # Q_res_ABC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), LDA_loading.T])
    # # print(Q_res_ABC_eq_1)
    # # print('Contribution Equation [1] of LDA hotellings T^2 matrix shape:', np.array(Q_res_ABC_eq_1).shape)
    # # Q_res_ABC = Q_res_RBC / Q_res_ABC_eq_1
    # # # print(Q_res_ABC)
    # # print('Contribution of LDA hotellings T^2 matrix shape:', np.array(Q_res_ABC).shape)
    # # Q_res_ABC = np.where(np.isnan(Q_res_ABC), 0, Q_res_ABC)
    # # print(Q_res_ABC)

    # #### ABC (2):    
    # eye_M = np.identity(input_len[1])
    # Q_res_ABC_eq_1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([LDA_loading, np.linalg.inv(np.diag(eigenvalues)), input_features])
    # Q_res_ABC_eq_2 = (np.linalg.multi_dot([eye_M.T, Q_res_ABC_eq_1, LDA_loading.T]) ** 2)
    # Q_res_ABC_eq_3 = np.linalg.multi_dot([eye_M.T, Q_res_ABC_eq_1, eye_M, input_features.T, Q_res_ABC_eq_1, input_features])
    # print(Q_res_ABC_eq_1)
    # print('Contribution Equation [1] of LDA hotellings T^2 matrix shape:', np.array(Q_res_ABC_eq_1).shape)
    # Q_res_ABC = Q_res_ABC_eq_2 / Q_res_ABC_eq_3
    # # print(Q_res_ABC)
    # print('Contribution of LDA hotellings T^2 matrix shape:', np.array(Q_res_ABC).shape)
    # Q_res_ABC = np.where(np.isnan(Q_res_ABC), 0, Q_res_ABC)
    # print(Q_res_ABC)    
    return Q_res, Q_res_CDC, Q_res_PDC, Q_res_DC, Q_res_RBC
```

Variables:

```
DiscriminantComponents = lda.fit_transform(X_std, y_Cat)
lda_f = lda.fit(X_std, y_Cat)
LDA_scores = lda_f.transform(X_std)
# LDA_loading = (lda_f.fit_transform(X_std, y_Cat)).T
LDA_loading = (lda_f.fit_transform(X_std, y_Cat)).T
eigenvalues = lda_f.explained_variance_ratio_
```

Input shape:

```
X_std: [50,7]
y_Cat: [50,] or [50,1]
```

Error I keep on getting is at the line:

```
    Q_err = np.mat(input_features) - np.mat(Q_eq_1)
```

And the error message is:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,7) (50,50)
```

How can I fix this problem and what should I use as input to Q-residual and Hotelling's T statistics calculation?

Comment: The error makes perfect sense because it is not at all obvious how the broadcasting should actually occur. It seems that `Q_eq_1` is a matrix with shape `(50, 50)`. Is that what you expect?

Comment: @ATony Well, I expect the Q residual outcome `Q_res` to give out an array of [50,1] or [50,]

Comment: But your error is before that and, as I mentioned, that seems to be because of the `Q_eq_1` shape. From your code, I would infer that you have 50 7-dimensional data points, in which case I would assume `Q_eq_1` are the LDA reconstructions and also should be `(50, 7)`, no?

Comment: @ATony Yes, You can check the edited question where I added the inputs

Comment: I think that I finally understand what you're trying to do. The problem is that you need to "invert" your LDA model to get the reconstructions from the LDA projections; that's what the $P_kP_k^T$ matrix in the $Q_i$ equation in the linked page is doing. However, to do that you need access to the LDA's model coeffs.

Comment: @ATony So, you are saying that I should use the `LDA.coef_` as LDA loading and input it into the equation?

Comment: @ATony I tried to changing code for Q-residual to `q_res, q_res_CDC, q_res_PDC, q_res_DC, q_res_RBC = Q_Residual_index_LDA(input_features=X_std, LDA_scores=lda_f.covariance_, LDA_loading=lda_f.scalings_, eigenvalues=eigenvalues)`  and I get error at the line for `Q_CDC_eq1` due to eignvalues or `q_res, q_res_CDC, q_res_PDC, q_res_DC, q_res_RBC = Q_Residual_index_LDA(input_features=X_std, LDA_scores=lda_f.covariance_, LDA_loading=lda_f.coef_, eigenvalues=eigenvalues)` the error is `Q_eq_2 = np.identity(input_len[1]) - Q_eq_1, operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,7) (5,5)`